# PHP: Add html icons to a script

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I need to **add the same icon to each of the li class** that are generated automatically by a PHP script that Im using in a customized widget, in a Wordpress site.

This is the script Im using in a wordpress widget to display some child pages.

```
<?php
 $ancestor_id=24;
 $descendants = get_pages(array('child_of' => $ancestor_id));
 $incl = "";

foreach ($descendants as $page) {
 if (($page->post_parent == $ancestor_id) ||
    ($page->post_parent == $post->post_parent) ||
    ($page->post_parent == $post->ID))
 {
     $incl .= $page->ID . ",";
 }
}?>

<ul>
   <?php wp_list_pages(array(
                        "child_of" => $ancestor_id,
                        "include" => $incl,
                        "link_before"      => "",
                        "title_li" => "",
                        "sort_column" => "menu_order"));?>
</ul>
```

The code for the icon (has already a class asigned) that I need to be used is..

```
<img class='sideicons' src="http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/iconSidebar1.jpg" alt="" >
```

How can I make each `<li>` generated to include the same icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use css, the rules you need are `list-style-type` and `list-style-icon`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like to do it in PHP would probably be more trouble than it's worth... How about javascript or jquery?

```
$('li').each(function(i,el){
  $(this).prepend('<img src="path/to/image.ico" />');
})
```

If you need to change the *existing* source of an image, target with something like `$('li img')`

Change `.prepend()` to `attr('src','your/new/image.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using CSS? It is easier way to do. just assign a class to your ul and add a background image to li tags.

like:

```
<ul class="list">
    <?php wp_list_pages(
         array(
             "child_of" => $ancestor_id,
             "include" => $incl,
             "link_before" => "",
             "title_li" => "",
             "sort_column" => "menu_order"
         )
     );?>
</ul>


<style>
  ul.list li {
       background: url(http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/iconSidebar1.jpg) no-repeat left center;
       padding-left: 10px;
  }
</style>
```